# Private construtor in inner class initialized within outer class

Tags: java, constructor, access-modifiers

Is it possible to initialize an instance of an inner class which has a constructor marked as private from within the outer class. I was under the impression that once a constructor was declared private no one can create an instance of the class except from within the class itself. Example

```
Public class Outerclass 
    {
        newinstance = new Innerclass();

       private final class InnerClass 
       {
         private InnerClass(//paremeters)
         {
            //constructor declaration inside
          } 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner classes are members of their outer class so they have full access to all the other members, and all the other members have full access to them.

The access markers in an inner class apply only to unrelated classes. And since your inner class is private in itself, it is only accessible for construction from its outer class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into the Singleton Pattern. You cannot declare an instance of a class whose constructor is marked as private but you can always declare a static method in that class with a private property. So when you call that static method of the inner class, it returns the one and only instance of that class to the caller.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Having static methods to instantiate some class does not imply there will be only one instance of this class, so this is not a singleton pattern

Comment: Outer class can always access inner class members. And you cannot declare static methods in an inner (that is, non-static nested) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a public method on the outer class that enables to instantiate the inner class :

```
public void instantiateInnerClass() {
    myAttribute = this.new InnerClass();
}
```

However, you won't be able to access and manipulate directly instances of the inner class.